# Having a single quote inside a single quoted string

Tags: shell, zsh

My question targets Zsh, but from what I tried, it seems to apply to POSIX shell and bash as well:

I want to write a string containing literal `$` characters (no interpolation intended) and single quotes. Since the chapter on QUOTING in the Zsh man page says about single-quoted strings:

> A literal `'` character can be included in the string by using the \' escape.

I tried something like this (in an interactive zsh, before doing it in a script):

```
echo 'a$b\'c'
```

I expected that this would print `a$b'c`, but zsh tells me that I have an unclosed quote.

I am aware that I can use as a workaround

```
echo 'a$'"b'C"
```

but I still would like to know, why my original attempt failed.

Comment: `\'` can't be used within single quotes since backslash retains its literal meaning. The manual you referred to should have mentioned it. You can do `echo 'a$b'\''c'` btw

Comment: Looks not much simpler than my workaround. The manual I quoted was the zsh-man-page distributed with my Zsh. I now see that the bash man-page is better in this respect, saying _A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash_.

Comment: Searching for `single quote` in `zshall` manual led me to a similar statement though. In my opinion zsh is an old ksh clone decorated with shiny toys, I never use it

Comment: I don't think it came from ksh; too many incompatibilities and completely different approach in so elementary points such as globbing and parameter expansion. My guess is that it is either a documentation- or an implementation error. Given the many fundamental differences to POSIX-like shells, I would not surprised if the Zsh designers **really** wanted to have quoting differently, but documented it without actually implementing...

Comment: One of the first sentences in the manual reads *Of the standard shells, zsh most closely resembles ksh but includes many enhancements.*

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. Asides, I'm surprised why my question was voted for being closed, on the grounds that it were off-topic. As far I see it, it is related to programming and the problem might bite anyone, who, like me, is doing a lot of zsh programming. I have now posted the discrpancy between documentation and implementation to the zsh bug tracker and will update my question if I receive there anything of interest.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was my interpretation of the man-page, and I must blame myself that I have left out of my citation of the page one part which I thought is unimportant, but actually is relevant for this case. Here again the **full** sentence of the man page:

> A string enclosed between '$'' and ''' is processed the same way as the
>     string arguments of the print builtin, and the resulting string is
>     considered to be entirely quoted.  A literal ''' character can be
>     included in the string by using the '\'' escape.

Since Zsh has two ways to write a single-quoted String (one where the quotation, like in bash, starts with `'` and one where it starts with `$'`), I understood the *between ... and* part that it meant "in `$'` and in `'` -quoted strings, the `\'` escape works.

This interpretation is incorrect. What the man page means is that a quoted string which **starts** with `$'` and **ends** with `'`, can use that escape.

Hence my example can written as

```
 echo $'a$b\'c'
```

Comment: Bash also has `$'...'` quotes and they work the same way.